# How to draw Qt widgets in a QTabWidget in non-selected tabs?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

My `QTabWidget` has 2 tabs on launch.

- Tab 1 is the one that's opened upon launch.
- Tab 2 contains some widgets of which I take the `QSize` to later draw similar elements in newly opened tabs.

The problem is that currently the size of the elements is 640x480 (apparently the default value), if tab 2 was not shown yet. Once tab 2 is selected, the elements are "drawn" and get their sizes depending on resolutio, window size etc.
How can I force the drawing of the elements in the background without opening tab 2, so that I can obtain the sizes the elements would have if the tab was opened? `repaint` and `update` do not do that.

My current workaround is to launch with tab 2 open and switch to tab 1 in `main.cpp` between `myWindow.show()` and `myApp.exec()` but that seems a bit dirty.

Comment: Does tab 2 widget has a layout?

Comment: I think you might want to call `sizeHint()` rather than `size()`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks, that worked, if you want to make that an answer I'll accept that one,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons, a QWidget's `size()` method is not guaranteed to return its expected value until after the QWidget has actually been laid out and shown.

If you need to know in advance what a QWidget's size *would be*, you can call its `sizeHint()` method instead, and that will force the calculation to be performed right away, so that the correct size can be returned even if it hasn't already been computed.

Answer (score 1):

according to [Document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) resizeEvent was never called when the widget is not visible and also paintEvent. this is a normal routine for decrease processing effort and reduce the rendering process. if you want to know when a tab1 resized, reimplement(override) resizeEvent and say to tab2 must be resized.

Comment: Thanks for the info with the resizeEvent. But I don't want to know when a tab is resized but **how** to force the first resizing. It has been pointed out already that sizeHint() works here.